# unable to set the openvpn network to look for a specific subnet behind a specific client

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

I have an openvpn network I have client with the ip 10.8.0.2 and that client have this subnet 192.168.43.0/24 I want the entire openvpn network to look for the subnet 192.168.43.0/24 in 10.8.0.2

Here's what I've tried

`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 ! -d 10.8.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to 10.0.0.4`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE`

The ip 10.0.0.4 is the private ip of the vpn server

I have also tried the above with this

`sudo ip route add 192.168.43.0/24 via 10.8.0.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answar for my question.

first in the server configuration file i added this line

`route 192.168.43.0 255.255.255.0`

and also I've added this line

`client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/client`

the name of my client was `test` so i've created a file named `test` in the folder `/etc/openvpn/client/`
and then i added this line into that file

`iroute 192.168.43.0 255.255.255.0`